# textview and scrollview alignment is not properly adjusted

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, alignment, scrollview

I am implementing a layout where , there is a textview and a webview inside a scrollview. The issue is i want to keep same alignment to the webview and the textview . My code is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/relativeLayout0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/rela1"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:textSize="18dip"
     android:layout_margin="6dip"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_gravity="left"
     android:paddingLeft="7dp"         />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
         android:id = "@+id/scrollview1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

        <WebView android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wrote this line `android:paddingLeft="7dp"` to adjust the alignment ,however i dont want this. Please help me out

Thank Adv.

Comment: Please explain more. Screenshots might help (expected/current)

Comment: I want to start the text from same alignment which is not happening if i remove the paddingleft line .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property of `RelativeLayout` that allows you to [align two children](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignLeft).

You would need to do something like this:

```
<ScrollView
         android:id = "@+id/scrollview1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id = "@+id/rela1"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            >



            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingTop="10dp"
                 android:textSize="18dip"
                 android:layout_margin="6dip"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:layout_gravity="left"
                 android:paddingLeft="7dp"


                 />

            <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 layout_below="@id/lblTitle"
                 layout_alignLeft="@id/lblTitle"

                />

        </RelativeLayou>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I dont want to scroll the text view . So I put only the webview inside the scrollview

Comment: You can actually remove the ScrollView in that case. The WebView should handle any scrolling that needs to be done. You'll want to set match_parent for layout_height on the WebView though

Comment: If I set match_parent for layout_height of web view, will it not cover every thing else  in the layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view contain only one parent view
So you have to take one layout inside scroll view and put what ever you want in scroll view.

here is edited code:`enter code here`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rela1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_margin="6dip"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yaa that i know thats why i made scrollview and parent of textview siblings . I want to know is there any way to align the textview and webview present inside the scrollview cause I am doing this using a padding left. Thanks

Comment: I dont want to scroll the text view . So I put only the webview inside the scrollview .

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have three minor problems
1) `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` does not affect anything as parent is `LinearLayout`.
2) `android:textSize="18dip"` Text Size you should always provide in `sp`.
3) `android:layout_margin="6dip"` Because of this it has margin from all the side.

Change your code to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/relativeLayout0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/rela1"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     android:text="@string/test"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
         android:id = "@+id/scrollview1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

        <WebView android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank u, But it does not satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/logo"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/rela1"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingTop="10dp"
 android:textSize="18dip"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:layout_gravity="left"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
     android:id = "@+id/scrollview1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is same as what i post I think. please elaborate

Comment: I have removed android:layout_margin="6dip" and android:paddingLeft="7dp"

Comment: Or you can do one more thing just use android:layout_margin this attribute only